# Error: org.macports.fetch for port git returned: fetch failed

Tags: terminal, macos, macports, git

I'm having trouble updating Git under MacPorts. The problem has existed for a few days now. I uninstalled Git and now I am trying to reinstall it. There installation error is shown below.

Other ports update fine.

What is the problem with MacPorts Git? How do I fix it?

---

***Installation Error***

```
$ sudo port install git
Password:
--->  Computing dependencies for git
--->  Fetching distfiles for git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from https://distfiles.macports.org/
git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from https://www.kernel.org/pub/soft
ware/scm/git/
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.distfiles.macport
s.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://mse.uk.distfiles.macport
s.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://sea.us.distfiles.macport
s.org/macports/distfiles/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://lil.fr.distfiles.macport
s.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://nue.de.distfiles.macport
s.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://osl.no.distfiles.macport
s.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://fco.it.distfiles.macport
s.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://cjj.kr.distfiles.macport
s.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://aarnet.au.distfiles.macp
orts.org/pub/macports/mpdistfiles/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://nou.nc.distfiles.macport
s.org/pub/macports/distfiles.macports.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://jog.id.distfiles.macport
s.org/macports/distfiles/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://her.gr.distfiles.macport
s.org/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://jnb.za.distfiles.macport
s.org/distfiles/git
--->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://svn.macports.org/reposit
ory/macports/distfiles/git
Error: org.macports.fetch for port git returned: fetch failed
Please see the log file for port git for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.
org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_git/git/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port git failed
/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_
devel_git/git/main.log
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port git failed
```

***Tail of Git main.log***

```
$ cat /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macport
s.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_git/git/main.log
...
:debug:fetch Executing proc-pre-org.macports.fetch-fetch-0
:debug:fetch Executing org.macports.fetch (git)
:info:fetch --->  git-2.10.1.tar.gz doesn't seem to exist in /opt/local/var/macp
orts/distfiles/git
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from https://distfiles
.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from https://www.kerne
l.org/pub/software/scm/git/
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection 
to www.kernel.org:443 
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://ykf.ca.dis
tfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/mpdistfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://mse.uk.dis
tfiles.macports.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://sea.us.dis
tfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://lil.fr.dis
tfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://nue.de.dis
tfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://osl.no.dis
tfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://fco.it.dis
tfiles.macports.org/mirrors/macports-distfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://cjj.kr.dis
tfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://aarnet.au.
distfiles.macports.org/pub/macports/mpdistfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://nou.nc.dis
tfiles.macports.org/pub/macports/distfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://jog.id.dis
tfiles.macports.org/macports/distfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://her.gr.dis
tfiles.macports.org/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://jnb.za.dis
tfiles.macports.org/distfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: Failed to connect to 2001:4200:fffc::248:
 No route to host
:notice:fetch --->  Attempting to fetch git-2.10.1.tar.gz from http://svn.macpor
ts.org/repository/macports/distfiles/git
:debug:fetch Fetching distfile failed: The requested URL returned error: 404
:error:fetch org.macports.fetch for port git returned: fetch failed
:debug:fetch Error code: NONE
:debug:fetch Backtrace: fetch failed
    while executing
"portfetch::fetchfiles"
    (procedure "portfetch::fetch_main" line 17)
    invoked from within
"portfetch::fetch_main org.macports.fetch"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
:info:fetch Warning: targets not executed for git: org.macports.activate org.mac
ports.fetch org.macports.checksum org.macports.extract org.macports.patch org.ma
cports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:fetch Please see the log file for port git for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.
org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_git/git/main.log
```

Comment: you can install git-2.10.0 (which is available) or wait until 2.10.1 found its way into the repositories...

Comment: Thanks @klanomath. I believe the former version was installed, and it produced the error above, too. Its one of the reasons I uninstalled it. Do you know if MacPorts QA's this portion of their deliverables? Its been broken for days, and it seems like its easy to detect and fix. I'm guessing they don't know its a problem, so I'm wondering what the disconnect is.

Comment: I checked some of the above addresses and none contains the .1.tar.gz but all the .0.tar.gz